# REST how to handle query parameters when put to resource?

Tags: html, rest

I have a REST data service where I want to allow the users to create new items with HTTP PUT using different formats like json,xml,csv. I'm unsure how to best handle the format specification in the url:

```
PUT /ressource/ID/json
PUT /ressource/ID/xml
```

or

```
PUT /ressource/ID?format=json
PUT /ressource/ID?format=xml
```

So what is the best way to specify a format indicator?

If I specify the format with an query parameter and want to do a `PUT` how can I do this with curl?

```
curl -T test/data.json -d "format=json"  http://localhost:5000/resource/33
```

does not work.

```
curl -T test/data.json http://localhost:5000/update?format=json
```

works, but I would rather let curl build the query parameters instead of adding them by myself.

Comment: As you are creating a *new* resource, you should use `POST` instead. `PUT` is more about replacing the resource at a fixed location, where the client knows the URI, it seems very broken to allow the client to say what ID to use to store a resource. `POST` would have the user use a URI like `/resource` and the server will respond with the URI that can be used to access the new 'thing', like `/resource/666`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A general principle of RESTful web services is to use the features built-in to HTTP, when applicable. In this case, you can indicate the format of your PUT request's content by setting the [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) header to *application/json* or *application/xml*.

Comment: Unfortunately if you want to make this an open API, many people will be unable to use Content-Type headers. The sad reality is that you usually need to allow some hacks, even if you permit the standardized way too.

Comment: This is about the Content-Type of a request body.  I can't think of any situation where a person would want to specify this and not be able to.  If you're submitting a web form, for example, it's not going to be JSON, so this wouldn't be relevant.